# summation of results in mysql and then dividing the result by 2

Tags: mysql, sum

Again, to continue with my mysql noob questions :) I want the following to be just one result:

```
select sum(sales_today) from table1
union
select sum(sales_yesterday) from table1
```

So right now that gives me two results, how do I make it give me only one, the summation of the two results? And how can I do to apply further equations to the result, such as dividing it by 2?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT (SUM(sales_today) + SUM(sales_yesterday)) / 2 FROM table1
```

For more details on what you can use, see [MySQL Functions and Operators](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/functions.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can add Expressions like you add fields. For easier access you should use the "AS"-keyword to give meaningful names:

```sql
select sum(sales_today) as TodaysSales,
    sum(sales_yesterday) as YesterdaysSales,
    ((sum(sales_today) + sum(sales_yesterday)) / 2) as TwoDayAverage 
from table1
```